# C++ searching a .txt file for all occurrences of a string and listing all results

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to write a console utility for maintaining a court date list in .txt format so I can keep better and easier track of them. To that effect I started with a piece of code I liked, as a template, and worked my way upwards.

The problem I am encountering is with implementing a search function that goes through the whole file and lists all found occurrences of a string (namely a calendar type date stored in the format DDMMYY).

Sorry if my coding is far from being acceptable, but keep in mind that I'm just a computer passionate lawyer! :)

Without further jib-jabbing here is the code in question:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace std;

void name();
void ID();

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    system("color 0F");
    int ch1;
    cout << "1 pentru a introduce un termen nou" << endl;
    cout << "2 pentru a cauta o data" << endl; 
    cin >> ch1;
    if (ch1 == 1)
    {
        name();
    }
    else if (ch1 == 2)
    {
        ID();
    }
}

void name()
{
    system("cls");
    string name, salary;
    ofstream worker("termene.txt", ios::app);
    int ID;
    cout << "Termen la instanta : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Data termenului format ZZLLAA : ";
    cin >> ID;
    cout << "Client : ";
    cin >> salary;

    worker << name << " " << ID << " " << salary << endl;
    worker.close();
    cin.get();
    main();
}

void ID()
{
    ifstream worker("termene.txt");
    string name, salary, ID;
    unsigned int curLine = 0;
    string search;
    cout << "Introdu data format ZZLLAA : ";
    cin >> search;
    string line, line2, line3;
    if (worker.is_open())
    {
        while ((getline(worker, line)))
        {

            if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "Termen: " << endl;
                cout << line << endl;
                if (line.find(search, 1) != string::npos)
                {
                    getline(worker, line2);
                    cout << "Termen: " << endl;
                    cout << line2 << endl;
                    if (line.find(search, 2) != string::npos)
                    {
                        getline(worker, line3);
                        cout << "Termen :" << endl;
                        cout << line3 << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Bad command or court date." << endl;

                }
            }
            worker.close();
        }
        system("pause");
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: `main()` is called in `name()`?

Comment: And what problem exactly is?

Comment: There is no good in storing a string without parsing (escaping) in a file having lines with different fields!

Comment: Could you clarify your question. Please read Stack Overflow standards to keep this powerfull knowledge database efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Call `main()` does not look like a good idea. It can potentially create a endless loop which will consume the function call stack. Here the growing is limited by escaping standard input, but it still overloads and may overflow the call stack. Bad practice, avoid it. Create a `while` loop within `main()`.

The following code will prevent call stack overflow:

```
int main() {
   while(true) {
      // Branch your code
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Then, each time a function is called within the `while` loop, the call stack is released when the function exits. Therefore the stack does not grow forever and you avoid the stack overflow. By the way it is better to provide an exit condition  instead of creating an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use fgrep? of course this will only work on Unix.

fgrep COMMAND:

> fgrep command is used to search one or more files for lines that match
>   the given string or word. fgrep is faster than grep search, but less
>   flexible: it can only find fixed text, not regular expressions.

I think you can use UnixUtils to get a few commands on Windows as well.